# Treat array with empty values as true 'empty' in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this JSON data:

```
["","","","","","",""]
```

When decoded, it turns into:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => )
```

When I try to validate using empty() in PHP, it still returns `true`. I aware that PHP will accept that array as `FALSE` if it is only empty array: `Array()`.

Actually I intended to replace those empty arrays into an empty string.

How to treat that array with empty string as 'totally empty' array?

Thanks.

Comment: Filter the empty values out first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter it

```
$array=array_filter($array);
```

Without providing any further options, this will remove all empty elements from the array hence your array will become 0 length in this case and it will become *true* empty that you are looking for.

```
$array=json_decode('["","","","","","",""]');
$array=array_filter($array);
var_dump(empty($array));  // true
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/605017)**

And if you don't want to make any changes to the original array but just want to check if all values are empty you can do

```
var_dump(empty(array_filter($array))); // true. Original array remains same
```

Comment: It works. Apparently I am not fully explaining my case, actually I still need the empty indexes if there is an index with a value. But I still can handle with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Thats why i put in the second part in this answer :) figured you still needed those empty values for something